# show loading image before the content loads through jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

Hello mates just stuck with a problem.

i am using click() and load() function to get my content in a css class

```
      $("#feed").click(function(){
      $(".homefeed").load("feedcontainer.php");
          $("#elementcontainer").show();
      });

      $("#news").click(function(){
      $(".homefeed").load("n.php"); 
      $("#elementcontainer").show();
      });

       $("#info").click(function(){
      $(".homefeed").load("newinfo.php");
      $("#elementcontainer").hide();
       });
```

As you can see when i click a div then i am able to load a php file content in a .homefeed class container and it is working perfectly

all i want to show a loading image..like loading....loading..... before the content loads..
because when i click one of those div then it is loaded into homefeed container perfectly but it is taking some time so i just want to show user some loading image to keep them engaged

any guess how to achieve it now? 
thank you.

Comment: You try to remove `return false;`

Comment: i even tried it (._.) but still it is overlapping another content

Comment: Please provide your html code. or  change from `$(".homefeed").prepend(response);` to `$(".homefeed").html(response);`

Comment: @AyanAman I couldn't quite comprehend the point you want to make fully. If you made a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) of your issue, it would be easier for us to understand your problem.

Comment: is there any way to do it through load() fn? @AhosanKarimAsik

Comment: @AyanAman your error is `prepend` function. `prepend` is used for insert element before existing inner content..

Comment: i get it but i am asking can i do it through load() function too? because my code will take too much memory/bytes by ajax call for 7 divs @AhosanKarimAsik

Comment: Yes, may be. try that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this:** `$(".homefeed").prepend(response);`  change to `$(".homefeed").html(response)`

```
$("#info").click(function (e) {
$("#loadimg").show(); 
jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST", 
            url: "newinfo.php", 
            dataType:"text", 
            cache: true,
            success:function(response){
                $(".homefeed").html(response);
                $("#loadimg").hide(); 
            },
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery blockUI plugin. [jquery blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `.beforeSend` option in the jQuery AJAX call.   Note, that this only works if your AJAX call is asynchronous.   If you call it using synchronous, it won't do any animations/queries/callbacks (as jQ is busy blocking everything until your call comes back).

```
$.ajax({
  url: "http://myurl.dot.com.jpeg.image.file.chmtl.php.asp.cfm",
  async:false,
  cache: false,
  beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
    // do stuff here to do the 'loading' animation 
    // (show a dialog, reveal a spinner, etc)
  },
  done: function(data){
    //process response here
  }
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/